# Python C-API module initialization handler, complement of Py_AtExit

Tags: python, python-c-api

In a python script(module) any global function call will be executed each time I import/reload module. I call these module-level initialization function.

ex.

```
def init():
    print "Hello, this is module initialization function"
    print "init() has been called"

init()
```

Every time I import this module/reload it will print these lines.

Currently I have a Python/C API module, that I want to add module-level initialization function.

Is this possible to do using this approach ?

---

Another possible solution that I know, I may add another normal function, then call it via `PyRun_String` or other functions of the C-API.